# Very slow data transfer between my smartphone (Huawei Y6s) and Laptop (HP Elitebook 840G1)

Tags: data-transfer, lagging

So, recently I got a new Huawei Y6s and transferred all my data to my HP Elitebook 840G1. It is just 5GB of data with almost 45000 photos. It shows about 1 day on the PC transfer dialog box. I am very confused, I mean I transfer two to three movies up to 8GB of data and they transfer just fine.

I don't know, I think that maybe because of a large number of files, it makes the transfer slow. It is worth noting that a movie with about 4GB of data will transfer in just 10 minutes, but these photos though, are 45k in number but 5GB of data is taking forever to transfer.

What shall I do? What's a better transfer method?

Comment: firsly, if you are using a cable, check the inside of the usb side. is white, blue or black?

Comment: The estimated duration shown by Windows for MTP transfers are just wrong, ignore it. The overhead for a large number of files exists, not sure how large it is.